# Query issue selecting result from 1 table to another

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am not much of a code person, I am trying to run a query every 5 minutes in mssql.

```
Select user from Db1.dbo.tableA where requirement = 1 

update Db2.dbo.tableB SET point = point + 5 where user = user;
```

I want to get user from Database 1 Table A where the requirement is 1 in DB, then update that user in Db2 Table B to match the user and increase current points by 5.

I am really newbie at this.

Comment: sql-server or mySql?

Comment: Okay this is the Query `update Db2.dbo.tableB SET point = point + 5 where user in (Select user from Db1.dbo.tableA where requirement = 1 )`

Comment: What if I wanted to limit it a bit more, like a.requirement is equal 1 but there are more than 5 results from same source with a.requirement 1.... How could I make it so b.point + 5 is only to 2 results only from the same source?

And allow some sources to be exceeded over the limit...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE FROM` with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE b
    SET b.point = b.point + 5
FROM tableB b
INNER JOIN tableA a
    ON a.[user] = b.[user]
WHERE
    a.requirement = 1
```

Comment: What if I wanted to limit it a bit more, like a.requirement is equal 1 but there are more than 5 results from same source with a.requirement 1.... How could I make it so b.point + 5 is only to 2 results only from the same source?

And allow some sources to be exceeded over the limit...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @user <same datatype as in column>

Select @user = user from Db1.dbo.tableA where requirement = 1 

update Db2.dbo.tableB SET point = point + 5 where user = @user;
```

**Edit** This will work only if there will be a single user as a result of the first query. For multiple users, the answer by Felix is more suitable

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tableAuser
AS
(
    SELECT user FROM Db1.dbo.tableA WHERE requirement = 1 
)
UPDATE b 
SET b.point = b.point + 5 
FROM Db2.dbo.tableB b 
JOIN tableAuser a ON b.user = a.user
```